# Another way to use enumerate in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please help me substitute enumerate from my code:

```
        for i in self.get_diagonals():
        for j, _ in enumerate(i):
            if i[j:j + 4] in win_condition: #checks diagonally
                return i[j]
```

here is get_diagonals:

```
 def get_diagonals(self):
    diagonals = []

    for i in range(self.height + self.width - 1):
        diagonals.append([])
        for j in range(max(i - self.height + 1, 0), min(i + 1, self.height)):
            diagonals[i].append(self.board[self.height - (i - j + 1)][j])
    for i in range(self.height + self.width - 1):
        diagonals.append([])
        for j in range(max(i - self.height + 1, 0), min(i + 1, self.height)):
            diagonals[i].append(self.board[i - j][j])

    return diagonals
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range(len(i))`, e.g.

```
for i in self.get_diagonals():
    for j in range(len(i)):
        # do something
```